# Открытие сайта на Denwer на всех локальных компьютерах не через IP адрес

Tags: хостинг, denwer

Я создал сайт на локальном компьютере с помощью Denwer ("test1.ru"). Он открывается на других компьютерах только по IP-адресу моего локального компьютера (192.168.1.6). Как сделать так, чтобы на всех компьютерах, подключённой к моей WiFi сети можно было зайти не на "http://192.168.1.6/", а по адресу сайта, то есть "http://test1.ru/"? Возможно ли это сделать на Denwer'e? Уже несколько дней копаюсь, но решить проблему не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 вариант**

1. Купить домен `test1.ru` или любой бесплатный
2. Указать его IP адрес `192.168.1.6`

**2 вариант**

Если в офисе есть единый сервер, откуда все выходят в интернет. Там можно прописать домен `test1.ru` на IP адрес `192.168.1.6`

**3 вариант**

Если роутер поддерживает DNS или филтрацию по доменам, так можно прописать `test1.ru` на IP адрес `192.168.1.6`

Comment: Первый вариант не подходит, так как платный. Второй вариант не подходит, так как вероятно тоже платный, и не удобный честно говоря (у меня будет много сайтов, и я их буду то создавать, то удалять). Третий вариант... отлично.

Comment: Завтра проверю. У меня роутер с огромным колчиеством функций, так что DNS вероятно он должен поддерживать.

Comment: Для первого варианта можно использовать бесплатные домены, хоть и 3го уровня. Если вам не играет роли имя домена

Comment: @Lesperanza если роутер поддерживает, это да будет самым лучшим